# Create Incremental Azure Storage Accounts on every run

Tags: azure-devops, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

Looking for a script to autogenerate a new storage account 
with a prefix dev something like dev01.... and when i rerun the template should increment as dev02.. on second run and so on. 
I tried giving the parameters / using default templates in github. 
Issue is if i pass on a value under the value the system deploys it fine ,if i give the same name it would rerun and update the existing storage.
Instead i would like it to check if storage account exists and if not create a new account , please advise any pointers if any

### Sample Parameters.Json file im using :

"parameters": {

```
    "storageAccountName": {
        "value": "dev01"
    },
```

Comment: Thank you Soo much Tom that was a great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommand that you could use the Azure powershell script to customize your logic to do that.
The following is the demo code:

```
$resourceGroup = "rgName"
$storageAccount = "accountName"
$location = "Central US"
$SkuName = "Standard_LRS"
$kind = "StorageV2"
$i = 0;   
while(1)
{
   $storage = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccount 
   if($storage -ne $null)
    { 
      $i++
      $storageAccount = $storage.StorageAccountName + $i
      $storage = New-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccount -SkuName $SkuName  -Location $location -Kind $kind
    }
    else
    {
      $storage = New-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccount -SkuName $SkuName  -Location $location -Kind $kind 
      $storageAccount = $storageAccount +$i;

    }

   if ($storage -ne $null)
   {
     break;
   }

}
```

**Task:**

[image]